# Are there sub sigma algebras of the borel sigma algebra on the real line that are not sigma finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Im wondering if all sub sigma algebras of sigma finite measure space are also sigma finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example is $\{\emptyset,\mathbb R\}$.

Another is the $\sigma$-algebra of countable or cocountable sets.